# Writing to coredata when device is put to sleep?

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsarray

I have abit of a problem, I have a coredata object that is used to populate a UITableView. Each UITableViewCell has a couple of buttons that I am using as check boxes, when the user presses one of these text boxes I would like to update coredata and reload the UITableView so all of the arrays I have are updated to reflect the new data.

Thinking about this I have come to the conclusion that its abit redundant or overkill to be reloading the UITableView every time a button is pressed because some of these UITableViews will contain hundreds of rows with two editable UIButtons each.

So I thought that maybe I should update the current array instead then when the view is either exited or the device is put to sleep I could update the coredata object then? the only thing being I don't really know if this is the right thing to do or possible.

The reason this is such a problem is that when I change a button from say a tick to a cross if I scroll away then come back the buttons tick or cross s reverted to its old value.

I would like to know the best way to handle this case as I have never done anything like this before.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an NSFetchedResultsController and its delegate methods to populate the UITableView. Then when the user taps a button, you simply update the corresponding Core Data entity and not the cell. The NSFetchedResultsController will then call its delegate methods, and you can update just that one cell on which the user made a change.
Also, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you simple fid the corresponding CoreData entity, and use its attributes/properties to adjust the display of the cell.
Remember, that you must always use some data (NSArray usually) from which to read what to do for the cell at the indexPath when the tableView calls cellForRowAtIndexPath:.
This way, when the fetchedResutsController call its delegate methods, you can simply call reloadCellAtIndexPath on the tableView and then the tableView will call cellForRowAtIndexPath again. As the Core Data entity has been updated, your logic for adjusting the display for that cell will cause the cell to look as it should. It's important that you only ever adjust the way a cell looks in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and base the look on a CoreData entity. Change the look of a cell in multiple places, and you will get problems.